# Hide react-native-image-picker device camera's back button

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I'm using `launchCamera()` from react-native-image-picker.

When the user launches the camera and then clicks the back button the app closes. I guess this is the device camera's back button.

I'd like to understand why this is happening and if there is any way to hide the back button.

Comment: Have you tried handling the ```didCancel``` state?